# Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring

Tags: java, spring, forms

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
SaveBatchService saveBatchService;

@Autowired
MassSMSFormValidator massSMSFormValidator;

@Autowired
SingleSMSFormValidator singleSMSFormValidator;

@RequestMapping("/userRole/sms/mass")
public String massSMSPage(Map<String, Object> map,
        @ModelAttribute("massSMSForm") MassSMSForm massSMSForm) {

    map.put("title", "Массовая рассылка");

    return "massSMS";
}    

@RequestMapping(value="/userRole/sms/mass" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String massSMSProcess(Map<String, Object> map,
        @ModelAttribute("massSMSForm") MassSMSForm massSMSForm,
        BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;    
    MultipartFile file = massSMSForm.getFile();
    massSMSFormValidator.validate(massSMSForm, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        map.put("errorFlag", true);
        return massSMSPage(map, massSMSForm);
    }

    //and so on
}
```

And this is form:

```
<form:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    modelAttribute="massSMSForm">

    <c:if test="${!empty errorFlag}">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <b>Ошибка. </b>
            <form:errors path="file" />
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" accept="text/xml, text/plain" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><br /> <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

This page must upload file and check its name. As you can see there is a special method to handle POST requests. But my server says `Request method 'POST' not supported` after submitting. What is wrong?  Do I have to use `command` attr., instead of `modelAttribute` or what?

**UPD:**

Generated `HTML`:

```
<form id="massSMSForm" action="/smsc/userRole/sms/mass" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" accept="text/xml, text/plain"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><br /> <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="0cd9d283-2ca7-4adc-af4a-ce72a09ceaae" />
</form>
```

Also, if I delete `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, this message doesn't appear. I was trying to add `headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data"`, but no effect.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML for the form.

Comment: Can you show the full controller class? Your action points to `/smsc/userRole/sms/mass` but the mapping for the post method is `/userRole/sms/mass`.  Eg. the controller needs a class level annotation of `@RequestMapping(value = "/smsc") to work. Maybe that is the case, can't tell.

Answer (score 2):

You have repeated two times the same PATH without specify in the first one the request type.

Change the first one for

```
      @RequestMapping(value="/userRole/sms/mass" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Looks like is getting the first path

And looking the path of your html I guess you have a controller like

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/smsc/")
 public class MyController{}
```

Also in your method change the modelAndAttribute for

```
   MultipartHttpServletRequest defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest
```

And remove from the form as well. you´re sending a file not a entity

Comment: Well, smsc - is my app name. I think I don't need this statement.

Comment: Also WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/smsc/userRole] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: You got it, you have something wrong with your routes

Comment: No. I've got few controllers with smsc prefix. I don't really need that statement.

Comment: Also, if I delete enctype="multipart/form-data", this message doesn't appear

Comment: Ok then your problem is about how you expect to receive your data, look my new response.

Comment: Well, the same error. Are we talking about POST method?